# Updating RecyclerView with ArrayList inside and between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview, data-transfer

I have `MainActivity.class` with two `Fragments` both have `RecyclerView`. From **Fragment A**, I go to **Fragment B** using `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container1, fragment_b);` -->( In short data from `Sqldatabase` put into an `ArrayList`)
Now in **Fragment B** when I change some data in `single RecyclerView Card` I am updating `RecyclerView`  using  `onActivityResult` like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == SECOND2_LAUNCH){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){               
                  int modify_position = data.getIntExtra("key4", DEFAULT:0);
                  MyItem item = data.getParcelableExtra("key3");
                  data_list7.set(modify_position,item);
                  mAdapter_details.notifyItemChanged(modify_position);
                }
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

For Example I want to change items name at postions **1**,  **3**, **5** without reload all data like: `adapter.notifydatasetchanged();` I prefere use `adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position)`.
**Fragment B** has Recyclerview with dynamically loading  when `RecyclerView` in **Fragment B** loaded  all data, it refresh whole `Arraylist`, so data that I have changed before (Recyclerview load all) are not refresh only the last call `data_list7.set(modify_position,item);` works, earlier changing items are not showing or returns to the previos state (after RecyclerView load all data and refresh Arraylist) why?
Second problem is "heavier" beacuse data that I changed in **Fragmnet B** in `Recyclerview`, I must show in **Fragment A** when back button is press, I return to the **Fragment A** and then I must update this data too... (without reload all data).
Additionally trouble is that the **Fragment A** use different `RecyclerView Adapter`
So I have to send data and then refresh it at `onResume` or `onStart` method in **Fragment A** but how to do that.
These sollutions comes to my head: as regards second problem.
**1**.Sending data via: Parcelable
**2**.Sending data via  Intent
3.Implements my own interface in `RecyclerView_Adapter.class`
4.Maybe there is some ready method (built in Android) in `RecyclerView`or in `RecyclerView_Adapter`
5.Maybe I should do some changes in `onBindViewHolder` from there refresh my items...
If regards to first problem:
Code:

```
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){               
                  int modify_position = data.getIntExtra("key4", DEFAULT:0);
                  MyItem item = data.getParcelableExtra("key3");
                  data_list7.set(modify_position,item);
                  mAdapter_details.notifyItemChanged(modify_position);
                }
```

I should put into an **Array** or use **while/for loop**.
I need to use this many times:

```
data_list7.set(modify_position,item);               
mAdapter_details.notifyItemChanged(modify_position);
```

So that`a all, thanks in advance.

Comment: First of to reload Fragment A, you can change transaction.add to transaction.replace

Comment: Yes I know it, "add" is made by me conscious.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. You can store the data in Room database and observe it via `LiveData<List<MyItem>>` on UI and update adapter.

Solution 2. You can share ViewModel between two fragments without storing in database

Solution 3. Pass data between fragments via [new Result API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between)

Comment: I choose sollution number 3, beacuse it is much easier, for my first project, but I have 2 problems now. First problem with arrays. Passing data from Fragment B to Fragment A. I have the same cursor position, but diffrent position in Arrays ( for example In Fragment B edited position is 2 and in Fragment A this data is at position 4, so how to update ArrayList in Frag A? 
Second thing is how to call this many times? I can't assign it to variables beacuse I don't know how many times (I mean RecyclerView card) user will edit. I think I must use while loop with itterations right?

Comment: I think for this case storing data in database is preferred way. You can get updated record from anywhere. You can create in memory database if data is temporary

Comment: Can I ask you for an example?I have no imagination how to do that.

Comment: Here is about room database: https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47

Comment: I didn't know anything about Room Database. I made a tutorial allready, but I don't know what to do with my : ```Some_class extends SQLiteOpenHelper ```in this class I made the table with columns so this class must stay am I right?
 Now. When I make exemplary item it shows perfectly in RecyclerView but when I use database browsing program (for example Firefox has some extension for that) it shows me none columns earlier I have all the database structure (columns name and type etc) so my question is it is is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Did you setup your database via Room ?

Comment: Yes, I made it. In RoomCallback for example I start new AsyncTask and it works, but problems above are actual.

Comment: Can you share you code via gist GitHub? There is no need for async task

Comment: I thought that even Room Database queries( update or adding new data) must use AsyncTask... am I wrong?
I haven't use Github...
It looks like roomCallback works good but class extending SQLiteOpenHelper is not invoked. So my db.execSQL doesn't create Table never.
In my MainActivity have this: ``` DataBaseHelper myDatabase = new DataBase_Helper(this);```
So Table should create...
Earlier I save items like this :
```
 database = myDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
 database.insertOrThrow(Table_Name, null, values);```
Now I have only:
```itemViewModel.insert(item_get);```

Comment: There is no need to create tables manually when using Room. You provide entities which represent models(table) and Dao witch make queries to database and RoomDatabae builder class

Comment: So class DataBase_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper isn't needed?
How can I built my DatabseStructure like:
````  String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PRODUCT_NAME+ " TEXT, " + AMOUNT + " INTEGER);" 
db.execSQL(query)```
I think that each of these options (Room Database) or traditional code above should return me empty database(before I fill it) in database browsing program with full structure.

Comment: When I export my database I cannot to see structure like on this tutorial for example:
https://youtu.be/hDSVInZ2JCs?t=3470
I know he used traditional Sql, but roomDb shouldn't be the same?